# Динамическая загрузка сборки

Tags: c#, .net, assembly

Сборку можно загрузить следующим образом:

```
Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly.Load
    ("SampleAssembly, Version=1.0.2004.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8744b20f8da049e3");
```

Будет ли `PublicKeyToken` одинаковым на всех компьютерах?

Answer (score 2):

[Да](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.applicationid.publickeytoken(v=vs.110).aspx), при условии что сам файл сборки ровно тот же самый на разных компьютерах и подписан тем же открытым ключом.

P.S. Принципиально важно подгружать сборку по её длинному имени?

Comment: Ну, рекомендуемый метод загрузки — именно по длинному имени.